# How to get shared notes in Evernote Python API?

Tags: python, api, evernote

I do manage to get my own notes from my production account of Evernote.

However, it's impossible for me to get the notes that another account has shared with mine.

I do not know if it is because the methods are deprecated, but I do not understand it at all.

Any help, example code, or something would be very helpful!!

Thanks in advance,

ehe

EDIT:

The code I am using to get the notes someone has shared with me is the following:

```
def getEvernote():
    authToken= "my_auth_token"
    client = EvernoteClient(token=authToken, sandbox=False)
    userStore = client.get_user_store()
    user = userStore.getUser()
    noteStore = client.get_note_store()
    linked_notebooks = noteStore.listLinkedNotebooks(authToken)

    shared_note_store = client.get_shared_note_store(linked_notebooks[0])

    //Here, I manage to get the shared note store and the first shared notebook

    updated_filter = NoteFilter(words=' ')
    offset = 0
    max_notes = 40000
    result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)

    //What is shareKey???????
    auth_result = shared_note_store.authenticateToSharedNotebook(shareKey, authToken)

    //EDAM error
    result_list = shared_note_store.findNotesMetadata(auth_result, updated_filter, offset, max_notes, result_spec)
```

any help??

Thanks in advance

ehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here : http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note-sharing.php
(Check the "Listing All Shared Notes in an Account" part).

Do you have some code you could show ?

---

Here is some code that should do the trick :

```
import evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore as NoteStore

from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.api.client import Store
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import NoteFilter, NotesMetadataResultSpec

auth_token = "YOUR TOKEN"

client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=True)

noteStore = client.get_note_store()

# get linked notebooks
linked_notebooks = noteStore.listLinkedNotebooks(auth_token)

linked_notebook = linked_notebooks[0]

# shareKey for the first notebook
shareKey = linked_notebook.shareKey

# get the right noteStore
note_store_uri = linked_notebook.noteStoreUrl
shared_note_store = Store(auth_token, NoteStore.Client, note_store_uri)


# authenticate to the linked notebook
auth_result = shared_note_store.authenticateToSharedNotebook(shareKey,auth_token)

# get the share token
share_token = auth_result.authenticationToken


updated_filter = NoteFilter(words=' ')
offset = 0
max_notes = 40000
result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)

result_list = shared_note_store.findNotesMetadata(share_token, updated_filter, offset,             max_notes, result_spec)

print result_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Laurent.
But this link explains how to get notes that you have shared with someone else.

The point I'm looking for is getting the notes that someone else has shared with my account.

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_authenticateToSharedNotebook

Comment: Gonna start a new answer to try to explain myself better

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do. I just didn't take the time to write a clear answer. Sorry for that. I'll try to make a better answer today.

Comment: IT WORKS!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH LAURENT!!
cannot vote up because of my reputation!